# How to convert fitdistrplus::fitdist summary into tidy format?

Tags: r, tidyverse, broom

I have the following code:

```r
x <- c(
  0.367141764080875, 0.250037975705769, 0.167204185003365, 0.299794433447383,
  0.366885973041269, 0.300453205296379, 0.333686861081341, 0.33301168850398,
  0.400142004893329, 0.399433677388411, 0.366077304765104, 0.166402979455671,
  0.466624230750293, 0.433499934139897, 0.300017278751768, 0.333673696762895,
  0.29973685692478
)

fn <- fitdistrplus::fitdist(x,"norm")
summary(fn)
#> Fitting of the distribution ' norm ' by maximum likelihood 
#> Parameters : 
#>        estimate Std. Error
#> mean 0.32846024 0.01918923
#> sd   0.07911922 0.01355908
#> Loglikelihood:  19.00364   AIC:  -34.00727   BIC:  -32.34084 
#> Correlation matrix:
#>      mean sd
#> mean    1  0
#> sd      0  1
```

Basically, it takes a vector and tried to fit the distribution
using [fitdistrplus package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/index.html).

I tried looking at the [broom package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/), but it doesn't have 
a function that covers that.

Comment: What exactly is the output you want? I'm assuming a data frame, like with the `broom::tidy` functions that already exist, but with what columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `broom::tidy(fn)` you receive an error that says:

> Error: No tidy method for objects of class fitdist

This is because this function from `broom` only has a finite number objects that are "good to use", see `methods(tidy)` for the complete list. ([Read more](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html) about S3 methods in R. More [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html)).

So the function doesn't work for an object `fitdist` but works for a `fitdistr` object from `MASS` (more "famous").

We can then assign to `fn` that `class`, and then use `broom`:

```
class(fn) <- ("fitdist", "fitdistr") 
# notice that I've kept the original class and added the other
# you shouldn't overwrite classes. ie: don't to this: class(fn) <- "fitdistr"

broom::tidy(fn)
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
# term  estimate std.error
# <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 mean    0.328     0.0192
# 2 sd      0.0791    0.0136
```

Note that you can only see the `parameters`. If you wish to see more and organize everything as "tidy", you should tell us more about your expected output.

`broom::tidy()` gets you this far, if you want more I'd start by defining my own method function that works for a `class` `fitdist` object using as [reference](https://github.com/tidymodels/broom/blob/master/R/mass-fitdistr-tidiers.R) the `tidy.fitdistr` method, and adapting it.

---

Example of how I'd adapt from the original `broom::tidy()` code, using the S3 method for the class `fitdist`.

Define your own method (similar to how you define your own function):

```
# necessary libraries
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

# method definition:
tidy.fitdist <- function(x, ...) { # notice the use of .fitdist

  # you decide what you want to keep from summary(fn)
  # use fn$ecc... to see what you can harvest

  e1 <- tibble(
    term = names(x$estimate),
    estimate = unname(x$estimate),
    std.error = unname(x$sd)
  )

  e2 <- tibble(
    term = c("loglik", "aic", "bic"),
    value = c(unname(x$loglik), unname(x$aic), unname(x$bic))
  )

  e3 <- x$cor # I prefer this to: as_tibble(x$cor)

  list(e1, e2, e3) # you can name each element for a nicer result
  # example: list(params = e1, scores = e2, corrMatr = e3)
}
```

This is how you can call this new `method` now:

```
tidy(fn) # to be more clear this is calling your tidy.fitdist(fn) under the hood.
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
# term  estimate std.error
# <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 mean    0.328     0.0192
# 2 sd      0.0791    0.0136
# 
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
# term   value
# <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 loglik  19.0
# 2 aic    -34.0
# 3 bic    -32.3
# 
# [[3]]
#      mean sd
# mean    1  0
# sd      0  1
```

Notice that the `class` is:

```
class(fn)
[1] "fitdist"
```

So now you don't actually need to assign the `fitdistr` (from `MASS`) class as before.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you need, but you can try:

```
tidy_fn <- rbind(fn$estimate,fn$sd)
```

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23539/use-fitdist-parameters-in-variables