# Convert to dataframe: Model fit summaries of full factorial subsets of a dataframe

Tags: r, weibull, fitdistrplus

I have a dataframe with a variable and two factors

```
test <- data.frame(variable = rnorm(100,10,5),
                   factor_1 = as.factor( rep(1:2,50)),
                   factor_2 = as.factor( rep(1:5,20)))

test <- test[test$variable>0,]
```

I fit a Weibull distribution to **[full factorial](https://www.r-bloggers.com/design-of-experiments-%E2%80%93-full-factorial-designs/) subsets** and collect fit parameters like this:

```
DF <- split(test, list(test$factor_1, test$factor_2), drop = TRUE)

library(fitdistrplus)
fit.weibull <- function(DF) {
   scale <- summary(fitdist(DF[,1],'weibull'))[[1]][2]
   scale_sd <- summary(fitdist(DF[,1],'weibull'))[[3]][2]
   rbind(scale, scale_sd)
}
params <- lapply(DF, fit.weibull)
```

What I essentially want as final output is a dataframe, which includes `scale`, `scale_sd` and `factor_2` as columns. But my current output is difficult to convert to such a dataframe.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Think this was done similarly here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51434417/how-to-convert-fitdistrplusfitdist-summary-into-tidy-format

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found an ugly solution that works:

```
scale <- c()
scale_sd <- c()
name <- c()

for (i in 1:length(params)) {

  scale[[i]] <- params[[i]][[1]]
  scale_sd[[i]] <- params[[i]][[2]]
  name[[i]] <- names(params)[i]

}

DF <- data.frame("name"= as.character(name),
                 "scale"= as.numeric(scale),
                 "scale_sd"= as.numeric(scale_sd))
```

The `name` column actually includes both factors, so each row of the dataframe represents a full factorial subset.